Set value with expiration in spring data redis
In the DefaultValueOperations class of spring-data-redis, the set method with a timeout argument internally calls the deprecated setEx command. Despite the deprecation of SETEX in Redis version 2.6.12, it's still being used in spring-data-redis. Redis documentation suggests replacing SETEX with SET along with the EX argument (SETEX Doc).
I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I don't understand why this method is still being used after a decade. Additionally, How can I utilize the SET command of Redis when invoking the set(K key, V value, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) method of ValueOperations?
I attempted to extend DefaultValueOperations, but it's a package-private class. Furthermore, I prefer not to fully implement the ValueOperations interface.
